# Add new environment variable to a process launched by ProcessStartInfo.LoadUserProfile

Tags: c#, environment-variables

I'm logged on my pc with the user 'podosta'

**This is working fine**

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo("c:\myapp.exe");
p.UserName = "myuser";
p.Domain = "mydomain";
p.Password = SecureString;
p.UseShellExecute = false;
p.LoadUserProfile = true;
Process.Start(p);
```

Environment variables of the process are the environment variable of the user 'myuser'
ex: %USERPROFILE% points to the profile of 'myuser'

**This is not working**

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo("c:\myapp.exe");
p.UserName = "myuser";
p.Domain = "mydomain";
p.Password = SecureString;
p.UseShellExecute = false;
p.LoadUserProfile = true;
p.EnvironmentVariables.Add("MY_NEW_VARIABLE", "SOME_TEXT");
Process.Start(p);
```

Environment variables of the process are the environment variable of me 'podosta'
ex: %USERPROFILE% points to my profile 'podosta'
By the way, %MY_NEW_VARIABLE% is created

Why this behavior ?
I need to start an application with a RunAs, having the environment of the runned user and add some additional environment variable to the process.

Thanks

Comment: Can't access because it is not there or can't access because it has the wrong value?  Start cmd.exe instead to troubleshoot.

Comment: I edited my question. You are right, app can access the env variable but has a wrong value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you're seeing is basically document on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431(v=vs.85).aspx) for the `CreateProcessWithLogon` Win32 function which works in the background when starting a process for a different user (using `System.Diagnostics.Process`):

> A pointer to an environment block for the new process. If this
>   parameter is NULL, the new process uses an environment created from
>   the profile of the user specified by lpUsername.

So as soon as you specify *a single one* environment variable for the new process, you need to specify them all.

The problem now is the `ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables` property. As soon as you access it the first time (for a given instance of ProcessStartInfo), it will be automatically populated with the complete environment for the current user ([ref](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/ProcessStartInfo.cs,168)).

Take this line, which runs in the context of user "podosta":

```
p.EnvironmentVariables.Add("MY_NEW_VARIABLE", "SOME_TEXT");
```

It does two things:

1. fill the `p.EnvironmentVariables` with the environment of "podosta" (including "USERPROFILE=...podosta").
2. Add the new variable "MY_NEW_VARIABLE=SOME_TEXT" to that.

This combined set is then passed to the process launched as "myuser" and thus it gets the "wrong" (better: unexpected) value for "USERPROFILE".

If you want to make sure that you pass a `NULL` environment block to the underlying Win32 function, to get the behavior described in the quote above, you cannot ever "touch" the `EnvironmentVariables` property - not even iterate and dump it for logging purposes.

It is also not sufficient to do `EnvironmentVariables.Clear()`. That will not set the internal field to `null` and the `CreateProcessWithLogon` function is just passed an empty environment block, but not a null one.

If you fail to do so, you get all sorts of funny behaviours, for example the then-executing process will have a value for `USERPROFILE` that is that of the user that started the process, etc.

You might get around that stuff by calling `CreateEnvironmentBlock` via p/invoke, add your environment variables as needed, then calling `CreateProcessAsUser` (also via p/invoke), passing that modified environment. That is all not an easy undertaking, especially when you want all the features of the `Process`-class like output redirection, etc.

It is kind of unfortunate that the `ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables` property works as it does.

Comment: Wow, years later :-) My solution was to "So as soon as you specify a single one environment variable for the new process, you need to specify them all.". But of course I accept your answer because the behaviour is clearly explained.